# "when" + present perfect, "when" + present continuous

Tags: grammaticality, tenses, time

Is it grammatically correct to say

> I remember that there were two memorable times when I have helped people

Also

> I would like to talk about my experience when I was pursuing my master degree

Comment: Hmmm.  I believe ''was pursuing'' is not present continuous.

Answer (score 1):

> I remember that there were two memorable times **when I have helped people**

You are talking about the past - there **were** two times. So, you'd better say it like this:

> I remember that there were two memorable times when I **helped** people.

As for the second sentence, it's OK. But "was pursuing" is the *past* continuous tense, not present.

Comment: Thx a lot. Is it also OK to say: I remember that there were two memorable times that I helped people in?

Comment: @Msheeab you are welcome! Since you are talking not about a place but time, use "when". And if the sentence were about a place, I'd recommend "where".